# Swift, SpriteKit, Segue between GameViewController and MainViewController after GameOver

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I would like to close an SKScene after a Game Over and go back to the main menu.

From the MainViewController to the GameViewController, I made a Storyboard Segue with prepareForSegue to pass some data from the MainViewController to the GameViewController

In the GameViewController, I made like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)

        scene.viewController = self

    }
}
```

And then, I declared the View Controller in the GameScene.swift like this:

```
weak var viewController:GameViewController? = GameViewController()
```

I also have in the GameScene.swift the following function to call the endGameScene.swift:

```
    func endGame() {
    // 1
    gameOver = true

    // 2
    // Save high score
    GameState.sharedInstance.saveState()

    // 3
    let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    let endGameScene = EndGameScene(size: self.size)
    self.view!.presentScene(endGameScene, transition: reveal)

}
```

Finally, endGameScene.swift call the dismissViewControllerAnimated like this:

```
weak var viewController:GameViewController? = GameViewController()       

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    // Transition back to the Game
    /*let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)*/

    print(viewController)
    self.viewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Unfortunatly, the print(viewController) return nil and of course, it not close the ViewController.

Where am I make the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Create function like this

```
func goToGameScene(){
    let gameScene:GameScene = GameScene(size: self.view!.bounds.size) // create your new scene
    let transition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.5) // create type of transition (you can check in documentation for more transtions)
    gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.Fill
    self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
}
```

then just call `goToGameScene()` wherever you want this transition to take place.

You don't need to dismiss anything because it creates a new scene each time you transition.